# Shifting \newtheorem

Tags: amsmath, theorems

Is there a way to shift a theorem from amsthm ? I mean instead of having :

theorem 1.1 (title): BLABLABLA

You would have theorem 1.1 a little bit on the left and blablabla in the same place. Similarly, it would be something like this : (but without tcolorbox, here I don't need the rest of the functionnalities, the style of amsthm is sufficient)

[image]

I want that my definition ( which is for now classic ) has the same behavior as the green and orange box. The dimension is not a problem (I'll set the value of shifting )

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like this.  The main point is that the last argument to `\newtheoremstyle` allows you to put arbitrary code to format the heading.  You can make the heading stay within the margins by adjusting `\leftskip` at the same time you set the body font, i.e. in the third argument to `\newtheoremstyle`.

[image: Sample first part]

[image: Sample second part]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\newtheoremstyle{side}{}{}{\advance\leftskip3cm\relax\itshape}{}
{\bfseries}{}{0pt}{%
\makebox[0pt][r]{%
  \smash{\parbox[t]{2.5cm}{\raggedright\thmname{#1}%
  \thmnumber{\space #2}\thmnote{\newline (#3)}}}%
  \hspace{.5cm}}}

\theoremstyle{side}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{theorem}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Euclid]
  \lipsum[2]
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[Very long name]
  \lipsum[3]
\end{theorem}

\begin{definition}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Unfort. that will not be sufficient in my case... I have really small margin on my document. I would need to also move the text... I'll add a picture of what I've for now done so you understand. I search something similar to the boxes green and orange :

Comment: you see ? that the title is a little bit moved on the side and the text also a little bit. Sorry if I haven't been clear

Comment: You can adjust `\leftskip`, see my updated answer